# Set RoundedRect Button Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I tried to set Rounded button with the following but its disappearing from the view. if I removed the

```
takebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

then its displaying the rectangular button. help me to get the RoundedRect Button.

```
 takebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 325, 250, 40)];
    takebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [takebtn setTitle:@"Take Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    takebtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:205.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [takebtn addTarget:self
                action:@selector(takePhoto:)
      forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [nextview addSubview:takebtn];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code like that below:-

```
takeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10; //value can be change accordingly.
takeBtn.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Note:-  No need to import Quartz framework in ios7

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UIButton* takebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[takebtn setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 325, 250, 40)];
[takebtn setTitle:@"Take Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
takebtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:205.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[takebtn addTarget:self
            action:@selector(takePhoto:)
  forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
[nextview addSubview:takebtn];
```

Comment: +1 this is better answer considering the code given, as the OP code clearly indicates a leak in line 1 & 2.